# Finding $\sum_{a_1=2}^{9}{...\sum_{a_2=a_1}^{9}{\sum_{a_n=a_{n-1}}^{9}{a_n}}}$

Tags: summation

Let
$$f(n)=\sum_{a_1=2}^{9}{\sum_{a_2=a_1}^{9}{\sum_{a_3=a_2}^{9}{...\sum_{a_n=a_{n-1}}^{9}{a_n}}}}$$

A) How could one find $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{f(k)}?$$
B) How could one find how many terms there are in the sum?

For Part B, I know that the number of terms in $f(n)$ is $f(n-1)$ but I need a way to compute $f(n)$ and the sum in part A.

Comment: Hint: $a_n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$\sum_{a_1=1}^9 a_1=\sum_{k=1}^9 k=45;\\
\sum_{a_1=1}^9 \sum_{a_2=a_1}^9 a_2=\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot k=285;\\
\sum_{a_1=1}^9 \sum_{a_2=a_1}^9 \sum_{a_3=a_2}^9 a_3=\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot \frac{k(k+1)}{2}=1155;\\
\sum_{a_1=1}^9 \sum_{a_2=a_1}^9 \sum_{a_3=a_2}^9 \sum_{a_4=a_3}^9 a_4=\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}=3663;\\
\vdots \\
\sum_{a_1=1}^{9}{\sum_{a_2=a_1}^{9}{\sum_{a_3=a_2}^{9}{...\sum_{a_n=a_{n-1}}^{9}{a_n}}}}=\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n-2)}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: Could someone please help me understand why it is true that $\sum_{a_1=1}^9 \sum_{a_2=a_1}^9 \sum_{a_3=a_2}^9 a_3=\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and how you can generalize?

Comment: Note that:
$$\sum_{a_1=1}^9 \sum_{a_2=a_1}^9 \sum_{a_3=a_2}^9 a_3=$$

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}
1+2+3+\cdots +9 \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2+3+\cdots+9 \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3+\cdots+9 \\
\qquad \vdots \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \ \ \ \ \ 9 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
2+3+\cdots +9 \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3+\cdots+9 \\
\qquad \vdots \\
\qquad \ \ \ \ \ \  \qquad9 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
3+\cdots +9 \\ 
\  \vdots \\
\qquad \qquad9 \\
\end{pmatrix}+\cdots +(9)=\\$$

Comment: $$\color{red}{1}\cdot \color{blue}1+\color{red}2\cdot \color{blue}{(2+1)}+\color{red}3\cdot \color{blue}{(3+2+1)}+\cdots +\color{red}9\cdot \color{blue}{(9+8+\cdots +1)}=\\
\sum_{k=1}^9 \color{red}k\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=1155.$$

Comment: See also [Figurate numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number)